# error with JDO, Cursors and large data sets > 10000 entries

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the proposed way to process large datasets with JDO, a range, and a cursor. All works fine until 10000 entries, but as soon as more entries are processed, the task fails with this error message:

A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 202)

Can anyone tell my why something goes wrong here? There is no additional information in the logs. No exceptions thrown or logged, nothing.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 10,000, or in that range? Does your processing involve caching the results in memory (i.e., sticking into an array or map)? You might be running out of memory.

Comment: I haven't tried to fully nail it down, but in other constellations I got explicit OutOfMemory errors. The chunks I load are 200 elements each. I do not keep a reference to any of the returned objects, only data is extracted as a string. I just got a com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request datastore_v3.RunQuery(). - I have very hard times to figure out why the processing fails. Any idea on how the root cause can be found?

Comment: You may be running into a datastore limit. I'll have to go look. You're past the point where splitting the work across tasks, using cursors to pick up where the last batch left off, starts to be a good idea.